# How exception is serialized to json in filter?

Tags: spring-boot, jhipster

In a method of a filter I throw two different exceptions based on different condition:

```
throw new InvalidRequestException("no access token in Authorization");
```

and

```
throw new InvalidTokenException("access token has expired, but there's no refresh token");
```

I managed to trigger two exceptions, but the responses in postman were different:
For InvalidRequestException:

```
{
    "timestamp": "2018-10-11T13:36:55.781+0000",
    "status": 401,
    "error": "Unauthorized",
    "message": "Unauthorized",
    "path": "/api/account"
}
```

For InvalidTokenException:

```
{
    "error": "invalid_token",
    "error_description": "Access token expired: token details...."
}
```

I checked both exception extends ClientAuthenticationException, why the format of response differ?

How can I custom the exception handler for those thrown in filter?

Answer (score 0):

It's probably due to how JHipster translates some known exception types for Zalando's problem library. See ExceptionTranslator.java

Comment: the breakpoint can be hit, actually these two exceptions are not kind of a zalndo's problem, it maybe formatted by spring security oauth2, not sure.

Comment: I set breakpoint in AdviceTrait.class (both org.zalando.problem.spring.common and org.zalando.problem.spring.web.advice) in Intellij Idea, but cannot hit.

Comment: OK so maybe the Zalando track is wrong, have you tried to follow in debugger in step by step from the moment the exception is thrown until it gets serialized by Jackson?

Comment: not yet, after the filter is finished, there are many other filters in chain so that I lost my way soon during debugging, will try later.